# How can I pass an expression to a function while identifying variables in the expression with local variables of the function?

Tags: functions

I am very new to *Mathematica*, so I apologize if the answer is obvious. I could not find other similar question answered elsewhere.

Basically I have written the following

```
a = b*c*e*f;
fi = {b, c};
d[a_, e_, f_] := 
  Module[{b, c},
    x = D[a, {fi}];
    Return[x]
  ]
```

When I evaluate, I want `{20c, 20b}` as the output. Instead I get `{cef, bef}`. I also tried

```
a = b*c*e*f;
fi = {b, c};
d[e_, f_] := 
  Module[{b, c},
    x = D[a, {fi}];
    Return[x]
  ]
```

and ran `d[4, 5]` which again gave `{cef, bef}`. So the issue appears to be that `e` and `f` are not identified inside the function with `e_` and `f_` defined in arguments. Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what you are trying to do, but if you want to substitute values for the *global* `f` and `e` then use `ReplaceAll`. Look it up. This is not what functions are for.

Answer (score 2):

You are working too hard with stuff you do not yet understand. Consider the following definition of `d`, which does exactly what you code does, but more concisely and efficiently.

```
a = b*c*e*f;
fi = {b, c};
d[expr_, vars_] := D[expr, {vars}]
```

Then

```
d[a, fi] /. {e -> 2, f -> 10}
```

> `{20 c, 20 b}`

gives the result you want. But `d` only saves you from writing one set of braces. Why bother with `d`? Just evaluate

```
D[a, {fi}] /. {e -> 2, f -> 10}
```

Here is what, in my opinion, is a more useful way to define `d`. It adds an argument for giving the substitution rules with a default values the means no substitutions.

```
Clear[d]
d[expr_, vars_, rules_: {}] := D[expr /. rules, {vars}]
```

Now you can write

```
d[a, fi, {e -> 2, f -> 10}]
```

> `{20 c, 20 b}`

and the following all do what you might expect them to.

```
d[a, fi]
```

> `{c e f, b e f}`

```
d[a, fi, b -> 2]
```

> `{0, 2 e f}`